# Device is shown in the anonymous list and Not included list both

Tags: ios, iphone, testflight

I am trying to upload a build to testflight which is sent to the team of my client, for testing. I have embedded the provision profile in the ipa itself. My Client have 4 people on his team who needs to to access the ipa. However one of them is not able to install the ipa on his device.

When I upload and the permissions page opens, I can see that the UDID of the person who's not able to install the app, is listed in `Anonymous Devices In The Provisioning Profile`, however he's included in the team and is a teammate. The weird thing is his name and the same device is also include in the `Teammate Devices Not On This Profile`.

I have matched the UDID letter by letter and both are same, how come the device is included as anonymous device, but is not available as teammate and when I send the Anonymous ipa link manually to him, it doesn't allow him to install.

I've tried by sending the build directly, to be installed via IPCU, but it gives the following error

```
A valid provisioning profile for this executable was not found
```

Can you please guide me, if I am doing anything wrong here. I have been struggling this issue for a week now :-(

Comment: if so urgent you can use diawi.com for now

Comment: It seems like, That's user's UDID is not in the provisioning Profile

Comment: @RajanBalana I've already checked, letter by letter that the UDID is included in the profile. I've checked with testflight and with Apple developer portal too. I tried to regenerate the provision, download and embbed it separately too with no success :-(

Comment: Is the Project ID matching with the provisioning Profile ? It seems to be a problem then.

Comment: @amar thanks I am trying it now. WIll let you know if that works

Comment: You mean the identifier? Yeah it's matching. The funny thing is everyone else is able to install the ipa, the one on anonymous device list too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently I contacted that guy and accessed his mac using teamviewer and then get to know that he in fact gave me wrong UDID. I put in the correct UDID in the provisioning profile and re-uploaded it and it worked. Thanks for the support though :-)